# Why does C++ template argument deduction fail to deduce the elements of a std::array?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction, stdarray

### The Problem

Considering the following (C++20) code

```cpp
#include <array>

// class template depends on array of ints
template<std::size_t N, std::array<int, N> arr>
struct S {};

// fix array length (for convenience)
template<int x>
using U = S<1, std::array{x}>;

// function template depends on array element only
template<int x>
auto func(U<x>) {}

int main() {
    func(U<2>{}); // error: compiler fails to deduce `x = 2`
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0A//+class+template+depends+on+array+of+ints%0Atemplate%3Cstd::size_t+N,+std::array%3Cint,+N%3E+arr%3E%0Astruct+S+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A//+fix+array+length+(for+convenience)%0Atemplate%3Cint+x%3E%0Ausing+U+%3D+S%3C1,+std::array%7Bx%7D%3E%3B%0A%0A//+function+template+depends+on+array+element+only%0Atemplate%3Cint+x%3E%0Aauto+func(U%3Cx%3E)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++func(U%3C2%3E%7B%7D)%3B+//+error:+gcc+and+clang+fail+to+%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.129380053908356,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:47.870619946091644,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Why does the compiler not deduce `x = 2` for the call of `func`?

### Expectation

Since using `std::array`s as template arguments is possible and comparison of them is `constexpr` I am surprised that this does not compile.

For any hints regarding why this seemingly simple deduction is not possible for the compilers I would be grateful!

### Context

The following variations do compile but are in my opinion less desirable and I want to avoid them if possible:

#### Variation 1

One variation is to provide an explicit template parameter as in

```cpp
    func<2>(U<2>{})
```

But this is not convenient and leads to repetition.

#### Variation 2

Another possible variation is to carry the explicit template argument around and then restrict the template as in

```cpp
template<std::size_t N, std::array<int, N> arr>
auto func(S<N, arr>) requires (N == 1) {}
```

This has the disadvantage to being very verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-type template argument containing a template parameter in a subexpression (rather than as the full argument) is a non-deduced context. (See [[temp.deduct.type]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#5.3).)

In other words when deducing the function argument of type `S<1, std::array{2}>` against the function parameter type `S<1, std::array{x}>`, then `std::array{x}` is an undeduced context because `x`, a template parameter, appears as a subexpression.

So `std::array{x}` can't be used to deduce the template argument for `x`.

The reason for this rule is that it is generally impossible to match `std::array{2}` against `std::array{x}`.

When the matching is done the compiler doesn't have the expression `std::array{2}` anymore. It just has an object of type `std::array<int, 1>` created from that expression and is supposed to figure out which value `x` needs to be given to the initializer to make an object with the same value (in the structural equality sense used for template argument identity). We know because of how `std::array` is defined that this requires `x` to be `2`, but in general for other types any argument to the constructor could produce objects of any value. It is impossible to formulate a general rule to perform this matching.

---

I am not exactly sure what your intention with the function is, but if you are just trying to make sure that the function is callable only if `N == 1` then

```
template<auto arr>
auto func(S<1, arr>) {}
```

will do. Now the non-type template argument to `S` is the template parameter `arr` as a whole, not as a subexpression. Now the compiler doesn't have to figure out for which values of `arr` the expression evaluates to match the value of the corresponding non-type template argument in the function argument. It can just assume that `arr` is exactly equal to it.